# basic orientation change code to relayout UI components in Corona SDK using graphics 2.0

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Anyone able to spot the issues here?  When I run this and toggle between portrait and landscape it does not work as expected (re width of rectangles following changing size of the effective width)

Try to get what the basic (simple) concept/approach is to handle autosizing UI elements to support Portrait and Landscape...

```
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )
local WIDTH_PERCENT = 0.8
local myGroup = display.newGroup()

local myRoundedRect = display.newRoundedRect(myGroup, 0,0, display.contentWidth * WIDTH_PERCENT, 50, 25)
myRoundedRect.strokeWidth = 3
myRoundedRect:setFillColor(0,1,0)
myRoundedRect:setStrokeColor(1,0,0)
myRoundedRect.y = 25

local myRoundedRect2 = display.newRoundedRect(myGroup, 0,0, display.contentWidth * WIDTH_PERCENT, 50, 25)
myRoundedRect2.strokeWidth = 3
myRoundedRect2:setFillColor(0,0,1)
myRoundedRect2:setStrokeColor(1,0,0)
myRoundedRect2.y = 75

local function positionItems()
    myRoundedRect.width = display.contentWidth * WIDTH_PERCENT
    myRoundedRect2.width = display.contentWidth * WIDTH_PERCENT

    myRoundedRect.x = display.contentWidth/2
    myRoundedRect2.x = display.contentWidth/2
end
positionItems()

local function onOrientationChange( event )
    positionItems()
end
Runtime:addEventListener( "orientation", onOrientationChange )
```

UPDATE:

It seems to be an issue with setting the width programatically of a Rectangle after it is already in place.  I'm assume this is the basic operation that corona supports.  So what I'm seeing with the below code is:

- If initially set to say a width of 1000 for the square as you toggle orientation it decreases in size each time until you can't see it
- If you set initially to say 10 you get a really weird pattern indeed
- After you reset the size of the rectangle and then read it back it doesn't have seemed to changed in value, but then that still doesn't explain the above two points

Code:

```
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

local WIDTH_PERCENT = 0.5
local INITIAL_BOX_WIDTH = 1000    -- pre immediate width/height setting by the "positionItems" functions

local myGroup = display.newGroup()

local myRoundedRect = display.newRoundedRect(myGroup, 0,0, INITIAL_BOX_WIDTH,INITIAL_BOX_WIDTH, 25)
myRoundedRect.strokeWidth = 1
myRoundedRect:setFillColor(0,1,0)
myRoundedRect:setStrokeColor(1,0,0)

local function positionItems()
    local displayW, displayH = display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight

    myRoundedRect.width = displayW * WIDTH_PERCENT
    myRoundedRect.height = displayH * WIDTH_PERCENT

    myRoundedRect.x =displayW/2
    myRoundedRect.y =displayH/2

    print("Set width to " ..  displayW * WIDTH_PERCENT .. " . Read value back from Rec = " .. myRoundedRect.width)

end
positionItems()

local function onOrientationChange( event )
    positionItems()
end
Runtime:addEventListener( "orientation", onOrientationChange )
```

Config (below - or just nothing gives same issue)

```
local aspectRatio =display.pixelHeight/display.pixelWidth
application =
{
    content =
    {
        width = aspectRatio > 1.5 and 320 or math.ceil(480 /aspectRatio),
        height = aspectRatio<1.5 and 480 or math.ceil (320*aspectRatio),
        scale = "letterbox",
    }
}
```

build

```
settings =
{
    orientation =
    {
         default = "portrait",
       supported = { "portrait","landscapeLeft", "landscapeRight","portraitUpsideDown"
         },
    },


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tracked down the issue to:

a) weird pattern just the large radius value I used in newRoundedRect
b) the core shrinking Rect seems to be a bug with newRoundedRect, as when moving to newRect things then start working as expect

Answer (score 2):

In the `onOrientationChange` function, the events that get passed are as follows:

```
"portrait"
"landscapeLeft"
"portraitUpsideDown"
"landscapeRight"
"faceUp"
"faceDown"
```

You would need to say something like this:

```
local function onOrientationChange(event)
  if event.phase=="landscapeLeft" then
  --Do code here
  end
end
```

Good luck hope this helps.

Comment: thanks - thats effectively what I'm doing - I think of narrowed the problem down to Graphics 2.0 issue with setting Rectangle widths after the fact... I'll update the post

Comment: No your not understanding what I mean. In your function, your calling that rectangle width whenever the orientation changes. Is that what you want?

Comment: I think so but I'm open to advice.  I really want to just support orientation changes in the UI.  So my understanding is you have to manually resize your UI components.  Note again I'm working in Graphics 2.0 and trying not to use compatibility mode.  If I'm missing something obvious re how to best support orientation changes would love to hear  :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to manually do recode the positions of the objects. Sorry :( no easy way out